# Python SQLAlchemy PostgreSQL find by primary key Deprecate message

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-utils

I use below code to find the object by primary key. Now I am getting this `Deprecated features detected` message.

How can I re-write this query to fix the deprecated message.

**Code:**

```
  def find_by_id(self, obj_id):
    with self.session() as s:
        x = s.query(User).get(obj_id)
        return x
```

**Warning:**

```
  LegacyAPIWarning: Deprecated API features detected! These feature(s) are not compatible with SQLAlchemy 2.0. To prevent incompati
ble upgrades prior to updating applications, ensure requirements files are pinned to "sqlalchemy<2.0". Set environment variable SQLALCHEMY_WARN_20=1 to show all deprecation warnings.  Set environment variable SQLALCHEMY_SILENCE_UBER
_WARNING=1 to silence this message. (Background on SQLAlchemy 2.0 at: https://sqlalche.me/e/b8d9)
    x = s.query(User).get(obj_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [filter_by](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.filter_by) instead of `get`.

```
def find_by_id(self, obj_id):
    with self.session() as s:
        x = s.query(User).filter_by(id=obj_id).first()
        return x
```